# Spring Data JPA Anniversary date

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table which stores customer info with their birthdays as DATE without time. How can I query to list birthday guys for today?

I tried some DATE and MONTH keywords but I failed.

Comment: What's the Java type used for the birthday field? Please show the annotations on this field too. Otherwise it is difficult to answer your question.

Comment: Spring jpa only supports AFTER and BEFORE on date types.

Comment: `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE DAY(SYSDATE()) = DAY(dob) AND MONTH(SYSDATE()) = MONTH(dob)", nativeQuery = true)`

Answer (score -1):

**You can create a method in Jpa repository to find customer with their birth date like**

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, UUID> {
 Page<Product> findByDate(@Param("categoryId") UUID categoryId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to query with date and month only.